A Conditional Sentence in Turkish
On a recent visit to Dalyan I asked two local people how the following sentence was to be translated into Turkish:

"If you would have come to Ankara, last week, you would have seen me."

A conditional sentence, past perfect tense, both clauses did not happen.
Here are the two translations:

(i) Gecen hafta Ankara'ya gelseydin, beni gorurdun,"


(ii) Gecen hafta Ankara'ya gelmis olsaydin beni gormis olurdun,".

When I tried this translation, analogously to examples given on p.215 of Asuman Celen Pollard's, "Teach yourself Turkish" e.g. "'Yerimde olsaydin ne yapardin?' = 'If you had been me, what would you have done?'", I came up with (i); not that I am any authority, as the book-title indicates, I struggle with the Turkish language.
Version (ii) is using the "mis" tense (Asuman's p.148): "...people use them (mis forms) to distnce themselves in some way from what they're saying". Three criteria are given:
(a) "saying what someone else said (indirect speech) e.g. 'Otel guzelmis' = 'They said the hotel was nice,'";
(b)"talking about something you're not sure of (therefore asking the listener to approve) e.g. 'Dogru mu yapmisim?' = 'Have I done it right?'";
(c) "for something you've just discovered (and are therefore not responsible for) e.g 'Aa! Corabim kacmis' = 'Oh! My stocking's laddered!'"
Things a person is not sure about or is not involved in. Do these conditions apply to the required example, above?
Both (i) & (ii) translate to the English; but, is there a subtle difference between them? If so, what might that be?
(Apologies: my keyboard is not (yet) geared to Turkish. There are dots on "i"s that should not be there; absent sadillas; missing double dots on "o" & "u".)

Have you consulted Geoffrey Lewis's Teach Yourself Turkish ? Despite its name, it's a scholarly account of Turkish grammar.

@BillJ: Thanks. I'll take a look.
